# Adding STI to Existing Table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I want to add STI to an existing table using a custom type column.  Let's call this taste_type whose corresponding model is Fruit.

In the Fruit model I have:

```
set_inheritance_column :taste_type
```

In my migration to add STI I have:

```
class AddSTI < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :fruits, :taste_type, :string, :limit => 100, :null => false
    Fruit.reset_column_information
    Fruit.find_by_id(1).update_attributes({:taste_type => 'Sour'})
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :fruits, :taste_type
  end

end
```

When I run the migration, I get the following error:

```
Mysql::Error: Column 'taste_type' cannot be null: ...
```

Any idea what's going? I can get the migration to run if I comment the set_inheritance_column in the Fruit model, then uncomment it after I run the migration.  Obviously, I don't want to do this, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `taste_type` column can't be null. The DB throws an error because you are adding a new column(that can't be null) to a table with existing rows.

One way to work around this problem is to add a default value to the column and subsequently reset the default value.

```
add_column :fruits, :taste_type, :string, :limit => 100, :null => false, 
      :default => "Sour"
change_column :fruits, :taste_type, :string, :limit => 100, :null => false

Fruit.reset_column_information
Fruit.find_by_id(1).update_attributes({:taste_type => 'Sour'})
```

Other way is to run the migration after truncating the `fruits` table.

Comment: Or if possible, re-seed your data with non-null fields.

Comment: User is adding a new non null column to a table with data. He wont be able to get past the `add_column` if the new column is not nullable.

Comment: In between add_column and change_column I had to do this to remove the default: change_column_default(table_name, column_name, nil)

Answer (score 0):

For those who find this using Rails 4, you can:

1. add the column, allowing null initially
2. Migrate your data, ensuring all pre-existing records have a `type` value
3. Use `change_column_null` to make the column null false after migrating the data.

   ```
   # my_migration.rb

   class MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
     class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base; end

     def up 
       add_column :fruits, :taste_type, :string, limit: 100, default: "Sour" 

       Fruit.reset_column_information
       Fruit.find_each do |fruit|
         fruit.update_attributes!(taste_type: 'Sour')
       end

       change_column_null :fruits, :taste_type, false
     end
   end
   ```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_null

[How to change a nullable column to not nullable in a Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966840/how-to-change-a-nullable-column-to-not-nullable-in-a-rails-migration)