# Rails Migration to make a column null => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I had originally created a table with column as

```
t.string   "email",  :default => "", :null => false
```

The requirement has changed and now I need to allow email to be null. How can I write a migration to make :null => true

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change a nullable column to not nullable in a Rails migration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966840/how-to-change-a-nullable-column-to-not-nullable-in-a-rails-migration)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Try:

```
change_column :table_name, :email, :string, null: true
```

Comment: Please consider using `change_column_null` as this `change_column` might not work in certain version

Answer (score 147):

[`change_column_null`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_null)  worked perfectly:

```
change_column_null :users, :email, true
```

The reverse has a nice option to update existing records (but not set the default) when null is not allowed.

Comment: I'd recommend using `change_column_default` along with this if you want `null` to be the default column value. Otherwise it will be `false` or `0`.