# Trying to change a column to "null: true" is not being reflected in schema after migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a column/foreign key, `resolver_id`, that I want to be able to have null values (ie: [Rails Migration to make a column null => true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900778/rails-migration-to-make-a-column-null-true)).  Let's say I have the following line in my migration:

```
def
    change_column_null :bugs, :resolver_id, true
end
```

However, after running a successful migration (ie, generate the migration and run `rails db:migrate`), the schema remains unchanged, besides the version number:

`t.integer "resolver_id"`

whereas I am expecting:

`t.integer "resolver_id" , null: true`

Is there something I'm missing?

I've also tried using just `change_column` like so:

`change_column :bugs, :resolver_id, :integer, null: true`

However, this is still not reflected in the schema.  The `rails g migration` and `db:migrate` work just fine, and the version number in the schema matches the latest migration.

For reference, here is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170502203934) do

  create_table "bugs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "error_msg"
    t.text     "description"
    t.text     "causes"
    t.boolean  "resolved"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "resolver_id"
    t.index ["resolver_id"], name: "index_bugs_on_resolver_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_bugs_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end

end
```

If relevant, the `resolver_id` foreign key is a reference a User model, ie:

```
class Bug < ApplicationRecord
  # Associations
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :resolver, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`null: true` is the default behavior. You will never see it in your schema, you will see either `null: false` or nothing.