# Ruby On Rails Change Column to Null, Not Work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I command in Terminal to change on column in database to not null, but It seems not work.

```
rails g migration change_column_null :Speaker, :surname, false
```

I got a file ChangeColumnNull But inside, it is nothing.

```
class ChangeColumnNull < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
end
end
```

Lecture Controller (Def Create):

```
class CplecturesController < ApplicationController
layout 'cp_layout'

 def create
@lecture = Lecture.new(lecture_params)

@lecture.save
redirect_to @lecture
end

private
def lecture_params
  params.require(:lecture).permit(:lecture_title, :lecture_day,   :column, :start_time, :end_time, :registered_speakers, :guest_speakers, :description)
end
end
```

Forms

```
 <%= form_for :lecture, url:lectures_path do |f| %>
 <form>
 <div class="form-group">
  <%=label_tag "Lecture Title" %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :lecture_title, :class => "form-control",   :placeholder => "Example: Why is Wordpress the best?" %>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966840/how-to-change-a-nullable-column-to-not-nullable-in-a-rails-migration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Erase that migration and write a blank migration with a better name and then fill it out by setting a default value. If you have a default value it will never be null.

```
rails g migration ChangeColumnOnTableName
```

Then inside that migration do the following:

```
change_column :name_of_table, :name_of_column, :data_type_of_column, :null => false
```

If you're only worried about it being null based on what a user enters, you could simply add a validation that requires it. In your model:

```
validates :name_of_column, presence: true
```

Comment: va185042:project Nixon$ rails g nameNull change_column :Speaker, :organisation, :string, :default => false
va185042:project Nixon$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
Nothing to annotate.
After I command this, nothing happen, not even file...

Comment: +1 for the validation in the model, but why use a default value instead of `null: false`?  Wouldn't you prefer to fail if data was input without a required field, rather than storing potentially garbage data with a guessed default?

Comment: @Joe that change_column goes inside the migration. Not as part of the migration command. You run them separately. I will update to show you.

Comment: @GoGoCarl valid point. depends on why you don't want it to be null. We don't really have that information. If it's a boolean field, for instance, I think you might naturally want it to be true or false instead of enforced. But don't disagree in principle. That works, too.

Comment: @toddmetheny  va185042:project Nixon$ rails g migration change_column :Lecture, :lecture_title, :string, :default => false
va185042:project Nixon$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
Nothing to annotate. Am i right, still nothing happen......Sorry

Comment: @Joe I updated my answer do NOT put that after migration. that goes INSIDE the migration that is generated.

Comment: @toddmetheny What did u mean inside MIGRATION??

Comment: first run this: rails g migration ChangeColumnOnTableName

Comment: Next open up the file that is generated

Comment: Inside the change method add change_column with the information that you want

Comment: after you run that first command you'll see something like this: `create    db/migrate/20160425211553_blank_migration.rb` That's the file you need to open. The change_column command will go inside the `def change` that is inside of that file.

Comment: YEAH, But the file I got is called 20160425211553_change_column_on_table_name.rb ....

Comment: @Joe. Open that file. Mine was just an example dude. You're taking everything too literally.

Comment: Inside that file is where you need to add change_column with the name of your table, the name of your column, the datatype and :null => false

Comment: Yeah, I think I got that......Thanks....But I just wonder why the original one in the RUBY ON RAILS GUIDE does not work .......

Comment: Anywhere I say something like `table_name` it means for you to insert the name of your table name. `column_name` is the name of the column you want to change. Same with data type. Only :null => false is exact.

Comment: class ChangeColumnOnLecture < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :lectures, :lecture_title, :string, :null => false
  end
end
ChangeColumnOnLecture: migrating ============================
-- change_column(:lectures, :lecture_title, :string, {:null=>false})
   -> 0.0031s
== 20160425220032 ChangeColumnOnLecture: migrated (0.0032s) ================ BUT AFTER I HAVE DONE THIS, IT IS NOT WORKING ON MY RAILS APPLICATION, WHEN I SUBMIT WITHOUT TITLE, I CAN STILL SUBMIT..WHY @toddmetheny

Comment: in `lecture.rb` add `validates_presence_of :lecture_title`

Comment: class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :lecture_title
end    I CAN STILL SUBMIT EVEN WITHOUT LECTURE_TITLE @toddmetheny

Comment: Post the params hash that is coming through to the form. Are you sure the record is saving? Did you restart the server? You have to restart after a migration.

Comment: Yeah I stop and start again. Yeah click submit, Nothing is saving...BUT NOT NULL should be tell me is can not submit and I should type something inside in lecture_title @toddmetheny

Comment: update your Question to include your form as well as the params hash being passed through the stack trace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110191/discussion-between-joe-and-toddmetheny).

Comment: Running to Doctor but will try to help later

Comment: As a note, modern Rails recommends `validates :name_of_column, presence: true` instead of the legacy style.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using latest ruby (2.5+) Here is the migration script to change fields from NOT NULL to NULL

`class ChangeEmailPasswordToNullableUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_column_null :users, :email, true
    change_column_null :users, :password, true
  end
end`